# Multivariate delta method gradient calculation with mixed moments

Tags: st.statistics, asymptotics

Here's a slightly simplified version of my problem (using fewer dimensions than what I'm actually solving).

Take $X \in \mathbb{R}^2$. We already know that $\sqrt{n}(X - \mu) \overset{d}{\to} N_2(0,\Sigma)$. Let the function $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^6$ be such that

$$\begin{aligned}
g(x) &= (g_1(x), g_2(x), \dots, g_6(x))'\\
&=({\hat{\mu}}_{10},\, {\hat{\mu}}_{01},\, {\hat{\mu}}_{11},\, {\hat{\mu}}_{20} - 1,\, {\hat{\mu}}_{02} - 1,\, {\hat{\mu}}_{22} - {\hat{\mu}}_{20}-{\hat{\mu}}_{02})'
\end{aligned}$$

where ${\hat{\mu}}_{rs} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{1i}^{r}x_{2i}^{s}$ is the sample raw mixed moment.

I want to test if $g(x)$ is a zero-vector, using the delta method to constuct my test. (not caring to know which elements are not zero in the case of rejection, so I'm looking at some $\chi^2$ test).

By the delta method, I know that

$$\sqrt{n}(g(x)-g(\mu)) \overset{d}{\to} N_6(0, \nabla g(\mu)\Sigma \nabla g(\mu)')$$

where $\nabla g(\mu)$ is the gradient

$$\nabla g(\mu) = \begin{pmatrix}
\left.\frac{\partial g_1(x)}{\partial x_1}\right|_{\mu} &
\left.\frac{\partial g_1(x)}{\partial x_2}\right|_{\mu}\\
\vdots & \vdots\\
\left.\frac{\partial g_6(x)}{\partial x_1}\right|_{\mu} &
\left.\frac{\partial g_6(x)}{\partial x_2}\right|_{\mu}
\end{pmatrix}$$

So (as far as I understand) we find the $\Sigma$ to get the normal asymptotic given above and, in a manner similar to Example 11.3.6 in *Testing Statistical Hypotheses* by Lehmann and Romano, we will have to use the delta method again with a variance stabilizing transformation so the variance is independent of the moments and we can get a consistent rejection region.

So

1. Am I understanding the process correctly?
2. If so, I feel like I'm misunderstanding how to calculate $\nabla g(\mu)$, especially with regards to the mixed moments? The notation seems vague to me, and I'm struggling to find examples that clear up my confusion. What I have is as follows:

Its obvious that $\frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{10}}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{01}}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{20}}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{02}}{\partial x_1} = 0$, as the functions don't contain the respective differentiating variables.

Less obviously to me, but following from other examples of the method, we have $\frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{10}}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{01}}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{20}}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial {\hat{\mu}}_{02}}{\partial x_2} = 1$?

And then its completely unclear to me how to find the partial derivatives of the mixed moments ${\hat{\mu}}_{11}$ and ${\hat{\mu}}_{22}$. So the matrix I have looks like

$$\nabla g(\mu) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
?? & ??\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
?? - 1 & ?? - 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I may be mixing up my variables as well.